# How to animate an Image View inside a zoomed relative layout?

Tags: android, imageview, touch-event, android-relativelayout

in my android application i have an activity with a custom relative layout (zoomable), inside of this there is a relative layout that contains an image view (associated with a picture), and two image view (associated with a canvas circle). Now, the circles can move overlay the picture(the user drag the circle with the touch), and this works, but when i try to zoom the picture and move the circles, these move with the same parameters of the layout when it is not zoomed, that is, their movement is amplified by the same factor of the zoom factor. For example, when the layout is zoomed, and i drag a circle just a little bit, this is moved too much! The code for the touch event on the circle image view is the below:

```
  @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent( MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                dX = (this.getX() - event.getRawX());
                dY = (this.getY() - event.getRawY());
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                this.animate()
                        .x((event.getRawX() + dX))
                        .y((event.getRawY() + dY))
                        .setDuration(0)
                        .start();
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Someone knows how to fix it?